# Как использовать отредактированный пакет npm в react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Сделал pull запрос по устранению бага на github для сторонней библиотеки react-native. Не известно когда изменения внесут, а пользоваться надо сейчас. Как правильно будет использовать измененный пакет в react-native?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить имя пакета на ссылку на ветку в вашем репозитории. Посмотрите примеры в справке [npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), как указать ссылку на Git.

Например для первого попавшегося [PR](https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/pull/2411) с GitHub'а:

```
npm i -S github:justinh00k/react-native-elements#addCardOverlayContainerStyle
```

Comment: спасибо большое вариант рабочий. Но больше интересует делает ли так кто на настоящих проектах, или такая ситуация не может возникнуть

Comment: Я так делал для pip, когда оказался в аналогичной ситуации (конечно, это не показатель). Правда, вместо имени ветки я указал точный хэш фиксации в Git. Пока что ничего не взорвалось))